# Need to Refresh the page by Deleting Cookie Unless Expected value is present in Cookie(Selenium Webdriver Javascript)

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a scenario where, Every time a cookie value will be 0 or 1 or Cookie will not be present

I wanted to refresh the page unless Cookie value is 0 or Cookie not present.

If cookie value is 1, Delete all the cookie and refresh the page and do the check again.

This has to happen till cookie value is 0 or Cookie itself is not present

Below script runs only once if cookie value is 1. How to make it run till cookie value is not 1 or cookie is not present in loop

```
log.step("Load Site from URL mentioned in Excel Sheet");

$browser
  .get(startingurl) //URL is given here
  .then(function () {
    log.info("Starting URL: " + startingurl);
  }) //Access URL mentioned in the Excel Sheet

  .then(function () {
    $browser.sleep(PageLoadSleep3s);
    let track = 0;
    cookie = "test";
    do {
      console.log("Cookie:" + cookie);
      return $browser
        .manage()
        .getCookie(cookie)
        .then(function (text) {
          if (text) {
            console.log("Cookie Value is: " + JSON.stringify(text));
            if (text.value != 1) {
              track = 1;
            } else {
              return $browser
                .manage()
                .deleteAllCookies()
                .then(function () {
                  log.info("Refresh the page");
                  return $browser.navigate().refresh();
                });
            }
          } else {
            console.log("Cookie Not found");
          }
        });
    } while (track == 0);
  });
```